# Firebase rule allowing new user inclusion and user-specific path privileges

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

After reading lots of tutorials and StackOverflow's questions I still couldn't figure how to do it.
All the tutorials start with the following rule:

```
"users":{
    "$uid":{
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
     }
}
```

But how to allow a new user in the users node when a new user log in (auth != null) and keep the read and write user-specific path privileges ?

In other words:
Is there a way to make a new user be inserted in the users node after login, and at the same time restrain him to only read and write to his own node ?

Another question. I have a write rule in another node with newData.exists(). In the Simulator when I try to write null data to the node it denies it as expected, but it allows me to write null to a child of this same node. Shouldn't the node write rule cascade to its children ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on - or give an example for - your second question please?

Comment: Never mid, sorry. It was not working because of another rule that I had set together with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules you have above will match `$uid` to `auth.uid`. So, for example if a user's UID is `cKzMyjImSBX6ybzeCCCjf0qbTym1`, they will be only be able to read & write at `/users/cKzMyjImSBX6ybzeCCCjf0qbTym1` in your database, regardless of whether or not this key currently exists (if it doesn't exist when written to, it will be created).

From the [Firebase documentation on rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security):

> Once a user authenticates, the auth variable in your Firebase Database
>   Rules rules will be populated with the user's information. This
>   information includes their unique identifier (uid) as well as linked
>   account data, such as a Facebook id or an email address, and other
>   info.

Comment: Ok, finally I have understood, the rules are related to the data not to the keys. So I don't need to worry about the users key (id) creation, but mainly with the access (read and write) to all the information stored below the key. Thank you Grimthorr to point me into the direction.

Comment: I am basically leaving my rules as the example above and am able to write and read from the database the way I wanted.